# Some variables are not being outputted in firefox FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

i have 2 queries in my code which are fetching data from two different tables. second query variables are being outputted in pdf (Firefox) but firs query variables are not being outputted. on other hand in chrome everything is right.
i have searched google but not found any solution. help is required and will be highly appreciated.
Here are my both queries:

```
SESSION_START();

require('config.php');
      $reg_number= "22110044";  //$_POST['reg_number'];
      $proj_id= $_SESSION['proj_id'];       //$_POST['proj_id'];
      $post_id= $_SESSION['post_id'];       //$_POST['post_id'];
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM applications WHERE reg_number=$reg_number" ;
      $sql2 = "SELECT proj_name, post_name FROM project_posts WHERE proj_id='".$proj_id."' AND post_id='".$post_id."'" ;
        $proj_name      = '';
        $post_name      = '';
        $chalan_form    = '';
        
$result2 =mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
    {
        $proj_name      = $row2['proj_name'];
        $post_name      = $row2['post_name'];
        $chalan_form            = $row2['chalan_form'];
        
        
    }
}
    
$result =mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $proj_id_f      = $row['proj_id'];
        $post_id_f      = $row['post_id'];
        $reg_number1    = $row['reg_number'];
      $app_name         = $row['app_name'];
      $f_name           = $row['f_name'];
      $mobile           = $row['mobile'];
      $email            = $row['email'];
      $cnic             = $row['CNIC'];
      $city             = $row['city'];
      $paddress         = $row['paddress'];
      $district         = $row['district'];
      $d_province       = $row['d_province'];
      $d_district       = $row['d_district'];
      $dob              = $row['dob'];
      $disability       = $row['disability'];
      $armedforce       = $row['armedforce'];
      $g_servent        = $row['g_servent'];
      $dcivilservent    = $row['dcivilservent'];
      $gender           = $row['gender'];
      $marital_s        = $row['marital_s'];
      $schcast          = $row['schcast'];
      $religion         = $row['religion'];
      $country          = $row['country'];
      $picture          = $row['picture'];
      $qualification    = $row['qualification'];
      $degree_name      = $row['degree_name'];
      $maj_subj         = $row['maj_subj'];
      $passing_month    = $row['passing_month'];
      $passing_year     = $row['passing_year'];
      $academic_term    = $row['academic_term'];    
      $total_marks      = $row['total_marks'];
      $obt_marks        = $row['obt_marks'];
      $percentage       = $row['percentage'];
      $grade            = $row['grade'];
      $inst_name        = $row['inst_name'];
      $sess_from        = $row['sess_from'];
      $sess_to          = $row['sess_to'];
      $already_emp      = $row['already_emp'];
      $org_type         = $row['org_type'];
      $org_name         = $row['org_name'];
      $designation      = $row['designation'];
      $job_desc         = $row['job_desc'];
      $job_status       = $row['job_status'];
      $start_date       = $row['start_date'];
      $end_date         = $row['end_date']; 
      mysqli_close($conn);
}
}
```

and here is my fpdf code:

```
require('fpdf185/code128.php');
//require('fpdf185/fpdf.php');


ob_start();

$pdf=new PDF_Code128();
global  $proj_name;
global  $post_name;
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',12 );
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image( 'images/logosmall.png', 5, 5, 40 );
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica', 'B', 24 );
$pdf->Text(55 , 18, 'Registration Form - ('.$proj_id_f.')' );
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',12 );
$code=$reg_number1;
$pdf->Code128(160,8,$code,40,10);
$pdf->SetXY(170,18);
$pdf->Write(5,$code);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(1);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(10,10,10);
$pdf->Line(5,27,205,27);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(0.3);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(10,10,10);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica', 'B', 18 );
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, '', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->cell(185, 8, $proj_name,'',1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',12 );
$pdf->cell(185, 8,'Applied For: '. $post_name,'',1,'C');
$pdf->Ln( 10 );
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','B',10 );
$pdf->Text(10, 55,'Personel Information: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10, 60,'Applicant Name: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45, 60,$app_name);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,65, 'CNIC: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45,65, $cnic);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,70, 'Address: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45,70, $paddress);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,75, 'Religion: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45,75,$religion,1);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,80, 'City: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45,80, $city);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,85, 'Mobile: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45,85, $mobile,1,1);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,90, 'Domicile: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45,90,$d_district);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,95, 'Disability: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45,95,$disability);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,100, 'Armed Force: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45,100,$armedforce);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,105, 'Deceased Civil');
$pdf->Text(10,108, 'Servant: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45,107,$dcivilservent);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(90, 60,'Father Name: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(115,60,$f_name);
$pdf->Image($picture,176,57,30,36);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(90, 65,'Date Of Birth: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(115,65,$dob);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(90, 80,'District: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(115,80, $district);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(90, 85,'Gender: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(115,85,$gender);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(90, 90,'Province: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(115,90,$d_province);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(90, 95,'Govt. Emp.: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(115,95,$g_servent);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(90,100, 'Email: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(115,100, $email);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(90,105, 'Marital Status: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(115,105,$marital_s);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(90,110, 'Sched. Cast: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(115,110,$schcast);
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,112, 'Country: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','U',10);
$pdf->Text(45,112,$country);
$pdf->Ln(60 );
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','B',10 );
$pdf->Text(10, 123,'Academic Iformations: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','B',10 );
$pdf->Ln(12 );
$width_cell=array(24,19,21,20,29,24,21,12,20);
$pdf->SetFillColor(193,229,252); // Background color of header 
// Header starts /// 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],6,'Degree Name',1,0,'C',true); // First header column 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],6,'Major Sub',1,0,'C',true); // Second header column
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],6,'Passing(M)',1,0,'C',true); // Third header column 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],6,'Passing(Y)',1,0,'C',true); // Fourth header column
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],6,'Academic Term',1,0,'C',true); // Fourth header column
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[5],6,'Marks /CGPA',1,0,'C',true); // Fourth header column
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[6],6,'Total Marks',1,0,'C',true); // Fourth header column
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[7],6,'% age',1,0,'C',true); // Fourth header column
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[8],6,'Divi/Grade',1,1,'C',true); // Fourth header column
//// header is over ///////
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
// First row of data 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],6,$degree_name,1,0,'C',false); // First column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],6,$maj_subj,1,0,'C',false); // Second column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],6,$passing_month,1,0,'C',false); // Third column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],6,$passing_year,1,0,'C',false); // Fourth column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],6,$academic_term,1,0,'C',false); // First column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[5],6,$obt_marks,1,0,'C',false); // Second column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[6],6,$total_marks,1,0,'C',false); // Third column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[7],6,$percentage,1,0,'C',false); // Fourth column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[8],6,$grade,1,1,'C',false); // Fourth column of row 1 
//  First row of data is over
$pdf->Ln(13 );
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','B',10 );
$pdf->Text(10, 148,'Employment Informations: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','B',10 );
$width_cell=array(50,35,23,29,29,24);
$pdf->SetFillColor(193,229,252); // Background color of header 
// Header starts /// 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],6,'Organization Name',1,0,'C',true); // First header column 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],6,'Org Type',1,0,'C',true); // Second header column
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],6,'Designation',1,0,'C',true); // Third header column 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],6,'Start Date',1,0,'C',true); // Fourth header column
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],6,'End Date',1,0,'C',true); // Fourth header column
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[5],6,'Job Status',1,1,'C',true); // Fourth header column

//// header is over ///////
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
// First row of data 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],6,$org_name,1,0,'C',false); // First column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],6,$org_type,1,0,'C',false); // Second column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],6,$designation,1,0,'C',false); // Third column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],6,$start_date,1,0,'C',false); // Fourth column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],6,$end_date,1,0,'C',false); // First column of row 1 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[5],6,$job_status,1,1,'C',false); // Second column of row 1 

//  First row of data is ove
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','B',10 );
$pdf->Text(10, 170,'Undertaking By Applicant: ');
$pdf->SetFont( 'helvetica','',10 );
$pdf->Ln(9 );
$pdf->MultiCell(190, 4, 'I  '.$app_name.' d/s/w ' .$f_name. ' hereby solemnly affirm that I have read and understood the conditions for applying for '.$post_name. ' and I have filled the form as per instructions and in the event any information contained herein is found to be untrue, I shall be liable to disciplinary action which may result in cancellation of my Application Form.' );

$pdf->Ln(15 );









$pdf->Output();
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

i have tried setting global variables but nothing worked these are three variables that are not displayed in pdf(firefox)

```
        $proj_name      = $row2['proj_name'];
        $post_name      = $row2['post_name'];
        $chalan_form            = $row2['chalan_form'];
```

also tried injecting variables

Comment: If you use server side to generate the pdf, it is not quite likely that the client side will behave differently in different clients (browsers) unless you have some special configuration imposed locally. Did you test this in another machine ? (e.g. firefox in another PC)

Comment: i have tried on different machine now chrome is also not displaying values

Comment: i can not figure it out that what is wrong with the $sql2, why its values are not being displayed

Comment: Please check the value of `$result2->num_rows;` (0, 1, or 2 ?)